# How can I Execute a code in background?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On a click event I have some codes that takes  about 4 seconds before the user can be redirected.

Is there a way that I can redirect the user, and the code will still be executed on the server? I

Comment: Spin up a new thread on the app pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a background thread (or a task on the thread pool) and redirect the user in the meantime. However, there's no guarantee that the task will have completed by the time the redirected request arrives. Do you need it to? Is it just "tidying up" or is it an action which needs to finish processing before you can display the results?

Note that I don't think there's anything to stop the `AppDomain` from being garbage collected while the thread is doing its thing... you may want to separate the long-running task into a separate service - fire off a request to that service, then redirect the user. If you have the concept of an ID for the request, you could include that in the redirect URL as a parameter, and then check whether the service has finished handling the task when the redirect request comes in.

Comment: So, If I create a webservice instead a thread, call the service and redirect the user, the service will still be executed? I dont need to send any response to the user when it finishes executing, I just need it to be executed without making the user wait..

Comment: @ShadowG: You'd want to make the webservice itself return very quickly, but add a job to the queue, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [create a new thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which calls a method, or use [asynchronous handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundWorker, does a great job if you are not very good with maintaining your own threads.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about using an [XHR Request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) or do you want to redirect the user, for the latter probably start running your process on another thread and send the response to the client..

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether or not the result of the expensive action affects what the user would see on the next page. Alternatively, you could use ajax to do the processing after the page has loaded.